# How can I solve MariaBD auto increment key problem

Tags: mariadb

I am new to MariaDB and I have an issue which seems to be easy at first side. I have a table with auto_increment id key, in which I insert some data from my app. Everything was working fine until I decided to delete all the records from the table. Now, it does not insert anything from my app. The only way to insert in it is to make it by hand and it starts from id = 1. Do you think that this is something normal for MariaDB?

Here is the code, which insert in the table:

```
$logs=array(
                  'customer_id'=>(integer)$token['customer_id'],
                  'driver_id'=>(integer)$driver_id,
                  'latitude'=>$this->data['lat'],
                  'longitude'=>$this->data['lng'],
                  
                  'altitude'=>isset($this->data['altitude'])?$this->data['altitude']:'',
                  'accuracy'=>isset($this->data['accuracy'])?$this->data['accuracy']:'',
                  'altitudeAccuracy'=>isset($this->data['altitudeAccuracy'])?$this->data['altitudeAccuracy']:'',
                  'heading'=>isset($this->data['heading'])?$this->data['heading']:'',
                  'speed'=>isset($this->data['speed'])?$this->data['speed']:'',
                  'track_type'=>isset($this->data['track_type'])?$this->data['track_type']:'',      
                          
                  'date_created'=>AdminFunctions::dateNow(),
                  'ip_address'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],    
                  'date_log'=>date("Y-m-d")
                );                              
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->insert("{{driver_track_location}}",$logs);
```

I also attach an image of the structure of table driver_track_location:
[image: table structure]

Comment: How did you delete all the records? TRUNCATE resets the auto_increment, DELETE doesn't.

Comment: Do you let the application determine the id?

Comment: I deleted them.. Was it the propriate one?

Comment: DELETE FROM syntax shouldn't reset auto_increment, so yes. See my other question + maybe you can add an example of the INSERT the application is trying to execute.

Comment: I edited my original question and add the insert part.